# Splitting Comma Delimited String That Has Un-escaped Commas That Shouldn't Be Split

Tags: regex

I am currently scraping html off a public website to build a more optimized database for my client's purposes.  This particular website does offer csv exports that would be much preferred vs scraping the html - but the csv has some limitations I just don't see any workarounds for.

Take for example this list of companies.  In html - its a simple ul, and I just loop over each li to get the individual company

```
<ul>
    <li>Lerner New York, Inc.</li>
    <li>Charming Shoppes, Inc.</li>
    <li>Lane Bryant, Inc.,</li>
    <li>Nordstrom, Inc.</li>
</ul>
```

In the CSV export - this data (one cell) looks like:

```
Lerner New York, Inc., Charming Shoppes, Inc., Lane Bryant, Inc., Nordstrom, Inc.
```

Splitting this string on comma is problematic because then I get:

```
Lerner New York|Inc.|Charming Shoppes|Inc.|Lane Bryant|Inc.
```

I wish it were just as simple as ignoring Inc. - but its not that simple.

Do you any of you reg-ex wizards have any magic you can offer up to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want the `, Inc.` parts gone or just split on `,.` (how should the output look like)

Comment: You don't want to parse CSV with RegEx, else if you **are sure** that that cases won't occure : `cell1,"do,not,split",cell3,"this "" is a single double quote","some, "",double"" ,quotes"" and,delimiters",lastCell` (there is 6 cells)

Comment: Two bugs don't make a feature. How about fix the CSV and not trash this even more?

Comment: In which programming language are you trying this? If it happens to be `PCRE`, you could use https://regex101.com/r/eVxCVi/1

Comment: What does the csv export of the data in the question look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex which has a positive look behind to only select commas (followed by one or more whitespace) preceded by a literal dot. So just split using this regex.

```
(?<=\.),\s+
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yu3JlX/1)**

Java code for splitting,

```
String s = "Lerner New York, Inc., Charming Shoppes, Inc., Lane Bryant, Inc., Nordstrom, Inc.";
Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=\\.),\\s+")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints,

```
Lerner New York, Inc.
Charming Shoppes, Inc.
Lane Bryant, Inc.
Nordstrom, Inc.
```